# Switch off line breaking in FPM log

Tags: php, logging, fpm

Is there a way to switch off line breaking in php-fpm log? It would be much more comfortable to log data without line breaks, cause when you grep something from log it outputs only first line of log entry, while there can be some additional info like var dump or stack trace that's being cut off if there were line breaks. It was good in apache, cause it escapes them, and it's better to use sed when necessary, but now it's kinda painful(

Answer (score 0):

Eventually came up with using ELK stack, which has multiline log splitting by pattern. You can actually do the same thing manually by using regexp or something like that, just dividing log stream by date-time pattern.

And of course, grep is not a good option when the system grows, please use one of many ready to use solutions for log collection :)